# How to write on image without using Canvas

Tags: android, image, textview, drawable, android-canvas

I want to write text on image but not using Canvas because Canvas text quality is too low. I need quality of text jus like TextView text. Is there any mechanism to get that? Sugesstions are welcomed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Frame layout for this....

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/

Comment: Are you sure `Canvas` text quality is insufficient for you? Have you tried turning on anti-aliasing?

Comment: @c2dm I want to write on image and save not just show the text. It can also be done by simply showing image then text with TextView by using Linear Layout.

Comment: @kabuko Yes i tried anti-aliasing true.

Comment: Internally TextView uses Canvas to render text. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/text/GraphicsOperations.java#GraphicsOperations.drawText%28android.graphics.Canvas%2Cint%2Cint%2Cfloat%2Cfloat%2Candroid.graphics.Paint%29
AFAIK, all UI widgets use Canvas to render themselves.